# Varnish 503 Backend Fetch failed

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, varnish

I have a server running Ubuntu 20.04, nginx and varnish with letsencrypt SSL.

I have installed PHPMyAdmin to the default server block and have another server block for my actual website running magento 2.4.3. This was all working fine until i installed varnish and now when trying to load either site i get the 503 Backend fetch failed error and when i try and load then on port 8080 from the URL i get a "this page cannot be reach" error.

I have configured nginx to listen on port 8080 for both sites, i have set varnish to listen on port 80. I have edited the vcl generated by magento to set the host and port to 127.0.0.1 and 8080 respectively as shown on https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish-configure.html.

The varnishlog show the backend is unhealthy error but i dont know how to solve this.
The output of netstat -tulpn is:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22007           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      48993/sshd: /usr/sb
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      302464/nginx: maste
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6082          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      304955/varnishd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25672           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      42533/beam.smp
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      44657/redis-server
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9100          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      14734/noderig
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      304955/varnishd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      302464/nginx: maste
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      162503/pure-ftpd (S
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      843/systemd-resolve
tcp6       0      0 :::22007                :::*                    LISTEN      48993/sshd: /usr/sb
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      302464/nginx: maste
tcp6       0      0 :::5672                 :::*                    LISTEN      42533/beam.smp
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      158505/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6379                :::*                    LISTEN      44657/redis-server
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      304955/varnishd
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      302464/nginx: maste
```

As you can see, varnishd is running on port 80 and nginx on 8080 but its almost as if port 8080 isnt listening. I have ufw enabled and "Nginx Full" is set to allow and i have also tried adding a rule to allow 8080 but this made no difference. Disabling varnish and trying again to load both sites on port 8080 results in the same "page cannot be reached" error so i dont believe this to be a varnish issue, but an nginx one, but why isnt it listen on port 8080?
If i try curl from the local server accessing localhost:8080 for example, it works and loads the default nginx page as expected. My PHPMyAdmin install is in a folder and that also works by using curl to access localhost/phpmyadmin. Does this mean it is then a firewall issue? Disabling ufw didnt help.

My mysite.conf my magento site is:

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
        server  unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}

server {
   listen 8080;
   listen [::]:8080;
   server_name staging.clicksaveandprint.com;
   return 404; # managed by Certbot
   set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/clicksaveandprint.com;
   access_log  /var/log/nginx/clicksaveandprint.com.log;
   error_log   /var/log/nginx/clicksaveandprint.com.err;
   include /var/www/clicksaveandprint.com/nginx.conf;

   if ($host = staging.clicksaveandprint.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    # PHP entry point for main application
    location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503)\.php$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
        fastcgi_buffers 1024 4k;

        fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
        fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=4096M \n max_execution_time=18000";
        fastcgi_read_timeout 6000s;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 6000s;

        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  HTTPS on;
        include        fastcgi_params;

        }
}
server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/staging.clicksaveandprint.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/staging.clicksaveandprint.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    # OCSP stapling
    ssl_stapling                            on;
    ssl_stapling_verify                     on;

location / {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
       proxy_set_header Host               $http_host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host   $http_host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header Ssl-Offloaded "1";
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  https;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port   443;
       #proxy_hide_header X-Varnish;
       #proxy_hide_header Via;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       proxy_buffer_size                   128k;
       proxy_buffers                       4 256k;
       proxy_busy_buffers_size             256k;
       }

}
```

magento nginx.conf. This is the default one from magento with no changes:

```
## Example configuration:
# upstream fastcgi_backend {
#    # use tcp connection
#    # server  127.0.0.1:9000;
#    # or socket
#    server   unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
# }
# server {
#    listen 80;
#    server_name mage.dev;
#    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/magento2;
#    set $MAGE_DEBUG_SHOW_ARGS 0;
#    include /vagrant/magento2/nginx.conf.sample;
# }
#
## Optional override of deployment mode. We recommend you use the
## command 'bin/magento deploy:mode:set' to switch modes instead.
##
## set $MAGE_MODE default; # or production or developer
##
## If you set MAGE_MODE in server config, you must pass the variable into the
## PHP entry point blocks, which are indicated below. You can pass
## it in using:
##
## fastcgi_param  MAGE_MODE $MAGE_MODE;
##
## In production mode, you should uncomment the 'expires' directive in the /static/ location block

# Modules can be loaded only at the very beginning of the Nginx config file, please move the line below to the main config file
# load_module /etc/nginx/modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so;

root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;

index index.php;
autoindex off;
charset UTF-8;
error_page 404 403 = /errors/404.php;
#add_header "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=Edge";


# Deny access to sensitive files
location /.user.ini {
    deny all;
}

# PHP entry point for setup application
location ~* ^/setup($|/) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;
    location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;

        fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
        fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=756M \n max_execution_time=600";
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

# PHP entry point for update application
location ~* ^/update($|/) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;

    location ~ ^/update/index.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/update/index.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # Deny everything but index.php
    location ~ ^/update/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/update/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location /pub/ {
    location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|custom_options|theme_customization/.*\.xml) {
        deny all;
    }
    alias $MAGE_ROOT/pub/;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /static/ {
    # Uncomment the following line in production mode
    # expires max;

    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
    location ~ ^/static/version\d*/ {
        rewrite ^/static/version\d*/(.*)$ /static/$1 last;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|svgz|webp|avif|avifs|js|css|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|html|json|webmanifest)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
           rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/ {

## The following section allows to offload image resizing from Magento instance to the Nginx.
## Catalog image URL format should be set accordingly.
## See https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/configuration/general/web.html#url-options
#   location ~* ^/media/catalog/.* {
#
#       # Replace placeholders and uncomment the line below to serve product images from public S3
#       # See examples of S3 authentication at https://github.com/anomalizer/ngx_aws_auth
#       # resolver 8.8.8.8;
#       # proxy_pass https://<bucket-name>.<region-name>.amazonaws.com;
#
#       set $width "-";
#       set $height "-";
#       if ($arg_width != '') {
#           set $width $arg_width;
#       }
#       if ($arg_height != '') {
#           set $height $arg_height;
#       }
#       image_filter resize $width $height;
#       image_filter_jpeg_quality 90;
#   }

    try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;

    location ~ ^/media/theme_customization/.*\.xml {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|svgz|webp|avif|avifs|js|css|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/customer/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/downloadable/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/import/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/custom_options/ {
    deny all;
}

location /errors/ {
    location ~* \.xml$ {
        deny all;
    }
}

# PHP entry point for main application
location ~ ^/(index|get|static|errors/report|errors/404|errors/503|health_check)\.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

    fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
    fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=756M \n max_execution_time=18000";
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_min_length 1100;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types
    text/plain
    text/css
    text/js
    text/xml
    text/javascript
    application/javascript
    application/x-javascript
    application/json
    application/xml
    application/xml+rss
    image/svg+xml;
gzip_vary on;

# Banned locations (only reached if the earlier PHP entry point regexes don't match)
location ~* (\.php$|\.phtml$|\.htaccess$|\.git) {
    deny all;
}
```

**EDIT:** adding port 8080 to ufw does now allow my phpmyadmin to work when connecting to port 8080, but i still get a 503 error when connecting to anything on port 80 with varnish enabled.

Output of  `sudo varnishlog -g raw -i backend_health`:

```
varnishlog -g raw -i backend_health
         0 Backend_health - default Still sick 4---X-R- 0 5 10 0.000624 0.000000 HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
         0 Backend_health - default Still sick 4---X-R- 0 5 10 0.000621 0.000000 HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
         0 Backend_health - default Still sick 4---X-R- 0 5 10 0.000652 0.000000 HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
         0 Backend_health - default Still sick 4---X-R- 0 5 10 0.000210 0.000000 HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
         0 Backend_health - default Still sick 4---X-R- 0 5 10 0.000214 0.000000 HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

The output for command `sudo varnishlog -g request -q "RespStatus == 503"`:

```
sudo varnishlog -g request -q "RespStatus == 503"
*   << Request  >> 11
-   Begin          req 10 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1641551164.244422 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1641551164.244422 0.000000 0.000000
-   VCL_use        boot
-   ReqStart       127.0.0.1 39792 a0
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.0
-   ReqHeader      Host: staging.clicksaveandprint.com
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Host: staging.clicksaveandprint.com
-   ReqHeader      X-Real-IP: 81.107.192.226
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 81.107.192.226
-   ReqHeader      Ssl-Offloaded: 1
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Port: 443
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   ReqHeader      Connection: close
-   ReqHeader      Cache-Control: max-age=0
-   ReqHeader      Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
-   ReqHeader      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36
-   ReqHeader      Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
-   ReqHeader      Sec-GPC: 1
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-Site: none
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: __tawkuuid=e::clicksaveandprint.com::n8RwZ5uipY2iBtEtSiR+wc7TP1jlMwD51gtYez+PiWZ4Xr/t3VxVX/BMIhUzfv0U::2; _ga=GA1.2.428376681.1618304758; _ga_01K4WXXY6B=GS1.1.1641392250.103.1.1641392407.60; form_key=VKzAhiJUg3HyT7jg; AMCVS_8F99160E571FC0427F0001
-   ReqUnset       X-Forwarded-For: 81.107.192.226
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 81.107.192.226, 127.0.0.1
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   ReqHeader      grace: none
-   ReqURL         /
-   ReqUnset       Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   VCL_return     hash
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   VCL_call       MISS
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Link           bereq 12 fetch
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1641551164.245036 0.000614 0.000614
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     503
-   RespReason     Backend fetch failed
-   RespHeader     Date: Fri, 07 Jan 2022 10:26:04 GMT
-   RespHeader     Server: Varnish
-   RespHeader     content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
-   RespHeader     Retry-After: 5
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 11
-   RespHeader     Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.2)
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   RespUnset      Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Pragma: no-cache
-   RespHeader     Expires: -1
-   RespHeader     Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
-   RespUnset      Server: Varnish
-   RespUnset      X-Varnish: 11
-   RespUnset      Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.2)
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1641551164.245126 0.000704 0.000090
-   Filters
-   RespHeader     Content-Length: 279
-   RespHeader     Connection: close
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1641551164.245228 0.000807 0.000103
-   ReqAcct        1233 0 1233 264 279 543
-   End
**  << BeReq    >> 12
--  Begin          bereq 11 fetch
--  VCL_use        boot
--  Timestamp      Start: 1641551164.244718 0.000000 0.000000
--  BereqMethod    GET
--  BereqURL       /
--  BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.0
--  BereqHeader    Host: staging.clicksaveandprint.com
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Host: staging.clicksaveandprint.com
--  BereqHeader    X-Real-IP: 81.107.192.226
--  BereqHeader    Ssl-Offloaded: 1
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Proto: https
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Port: 443
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Proto: https
--  BereqHeader    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
--  BereqHeader    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36
--  BereqHeader    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
--  BereqHeader    Sec-GPC: 1
--  BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-Site: none
--  BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
--  BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
--  BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
--  BereqHeader    Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
--  BereqHeader    Cookie: __tawkuuid=e::clicksaveandprint.com::n8RwZ5uipY2iBtEtSiR+wc7TP1jlMwD51gtYez+PiWZ4Xr/t3VxVX/BMIhUzfv0U::2; _ga=GA1.2.428376681.1618304758; _ga_01K4WXXY6B=GS1.1.1641392250.103.1.1641392407.60; form_key=VKzAhiJUg3HyT7jg; AMCVS_8F99160E571FC0427F0001
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 81.107.192.226, 127.0.0.1
--  BereqHeader    grace: none
--  BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
--  BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
--  BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 12
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
--  VCL_return     fetch
--  FetchError     backend default: unhealthy
--  Timestamp      Beresp: 1641551164.244824 0.000107 0.000107
--  Timestamp      Error: 1641551164.244834 0.000116 0.000010
--  BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
--  BerespStatus   503
--  BerespReason   Service Unavailable
--  BerespReason   Backend fetch failed
--  BerespHeader   Date: Fri, 07 Jan 2022 10:26:04 GMT
--  BerespHeader   Server: Varnish
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_ERROR
--  BerespHeader   content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
--  BerespHeader   Retry-After: 5
--  VCL_return     deliver
--  Storage        malloc Transient
--  Length         279
--  BereqAcct      0 0 0 0 0 0
--  End
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please provide the output of the following command?

```
sudo varnishlog -g raw -i backend_health
```

This command will provide logging information on the status of the health probe checks.

The fact that you get a `503 Backend fetch failed` probably means the backend is not available.

If the backend health logging is inconclusive, we can always look at the transactions that resulted in that `503 Backend fetch failed` error.

You can run the following command for that:

```
sudo varnishlog -g request -q "RespStatus == 503"
```

Please provide some logging output:

- A couple of lines from the backend health logging command
- A full log transaction for a request that triggered the `503 Backend fetch failed`

### UPDATE

I check the output of your VSL logs and the health check returns an `HTTP 404 Not Found` error. This means that the `/health_check.php` resource cannot be found.

That's a common error in Magento. As described in https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/configuring-varnish-magento/#fixing-the-backend-health-checks-for-magento-24 the health check endpoint depends on your Magento version.

Please replace the URL of your health probe from `/health_check.php` to `/pub/health_check.php` or vice versa.

Just ensure that the health check URL returns an `HTTP 200 OK` and Varnish should be able to consider the backend healthy.

Comment: I have added these to my original post. I have noticed that if i try and request http://staging.clicksaveandprint.com:8080 i get an error 404. All files are there and it was working fine before installing varnish and changing nginx port to 8080. This answers why i get that error, but not why i now get an error 404

Comment: please see my comment on the other answer. I have already edited that url to remove the `/pub`. I have also followed the instructions on https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360034631211-Troubleshooting-503-error-caused-by-necessity-to-change-default-Varnish-settings

Comment: My advice is quite simple: add a URL that works. Try the `health_check.php` in your browser. If that results in a 404, you still have the wrong URL. If `sudo varnishlog -g raw -i backend_health` starts giving you a different error, we'll work from there.

Comment: I have tried that and i still get a 503 error. accessing `health_check.php` or `pub/health_check.php` in a browser still gives me the 503 error and the `sudo varnishlog -g raw -i backend_health` command still gives me the error 404 output. All files are there with the correct permissions. I will add my full nginx mysite.conf to my original post to see if anything is incorrect in there

Comment: The 503 comes from the fact that the backend probe is failing. The 404 in the logs is because the health_check.php cannot be found. Try using the browser to navigate to the health check on the Nginx port `8080` rather than the Varnish port. This will allow you to bypass the 503 error. Running `curl -I localhost:8080/health_check.php` or `curl -I localhost:8080/pub/health_check.php` on the server could help you figure out which one returns a 200 and which one returns a 404.

Comment: I'm quite curious to see what's in `include /var/www/clicksaveandprint.com/nginx.conf;`, because apart from the `$MAGE_ROOT ` variable, I see no actual `root` configuration in your Nginx config yet. I'm assuming it's in the `nginx.conf` file you include.

Comment: I tried accessing `health_check.php` and `pub/health_check.php` on port 8080 in a browser and was getting an error 404. Curl also returns 404 for both. Is this because my magento site is not in my default nginx location, but a separate server block? The file is definitely in my pub folder. I have added the magento nginx.conf to my original post. I have not made any changes to this

Comment: Interesting that both return a 404. Based on the Nginx config files you shared, I can conclude that `/var/www/clicksaveandprint.com/pub` is the Nginx root. You mentioned that `health_check.php` is in the `pub` folder. So `/health_check.php` should work. Try accessing other files in the `pub` folder as well to see if something is wrong with your Nginx config. There's not a lot more advice I can give you at this point. If you figure out why the health check returns a 404 you fixed the entire problem and Varnish will no longer return a 503 error. Good luck!

Comment: I appreciate the help. Nothing in the pub folder is being found. Magento uses pub as its root from version 2.4 so this is why its set like that. I find it odd that it was working fine before i changed ports and enabled varnish. I've looked at various tutorials for setting up magento on nginx and my config files are the same (well very similar, i've added a few bits) and the nginx.conf is the default one that comes with magento so there cant be anything wrong with that one, all i've done is remove .sample from the end of the file name so if i do make any changes they wont be lost in an update.

Comment: I have another update. I've been playing around with my nginx config and now i've got it to the point where doing a curl request gets a 200 status from health_check.php on port 8080, but still getting a 503 error through varnish and varnish still reports a 404 error when running `sudo varnishlog -g raw -i backend_health`. Do you have any ideas now im getting a 200 status when running `curl -I http://staging.clicksaveandprint.com:8080/health_check.php`?

Comment: I have one more idea: add a `.host_header` property to your backend to ensure that the right host header gets sent while probing. This will result in the right virtual host configuration being selected in Nginx. Please also debug the incoming host header in your access logs to validate this hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks. now i seem to have a working site but im not sure if varnish is caching anything as i cant see anything in the http headers. I have `Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0`, `Pragma: no-cache` and `Cache-Control: max-age=0` as the only cache related headers. Health_check.php now reports a 200 status which is good and both port 80 and 8080 are working.

Comment: That's a different topic, Alex. Please accept my answer first and open a separate question for the cacheability of your Magento application. I'd be happy to assist with the Varnish-related side of this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase `first_byte_timeout` parameter like this:

```
backend www {
...
    .first_byte_timeout = 100s;
...
}
```

Comment: This is already set to 600s. My backend block is:   
```backend default {   
    .host = "127.0.0.1";   
    .port = "8080";   
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;   
    .probe = {   
        .url = "/health_check.php";   
        .timeout = 2s;   
        .interval = 5s;   
        .window = 10;   
        .threshold = 5;   
   }   
}```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me.

Please edit file `/etc/varnish/default.vcl`

```
.probe = {
    #.url = "/health_check.php";
    .request =
        "GET /health_check.php HTTP/1.1"
        "Host: your.localhost.domain"
        "Connection: close";
    .timeout = 2s;
    .interval = 5s;
    .window = 10;
    .threshold = 5;
}
```

After commenting out the URL line, and replacing your domain, you need to restart varnish.

Already once restarted, you can check it using:

```
sudo varnishlog -g raw -i backend_health
     0 Backend_health - default Still healthy 4---X-RH 10 5 10 0.400207 0.399852 "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
     0 Backend_health - default Still healthy 4---X-RH 10 5 10 0.378286 0.394460 "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
     0 Backend_health - default Still healthy 4---X-RH 10 5 10 0.365802 0.387296 "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
     0 Backend_health - default Still healthy 4---X-RH 10 5 10 0.400828 0.390679 "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
     0 Backend_health - default Still healthy 4---X-RH 10 5 10 0.362925 0.383740 "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
```

Please refert to https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11692#issuecomment-871181081

I hope this answer has been useful.